# Deleting a row in a Oracle 11g database using NetBeans

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, oracle11g

I am trying to delete a row in the database where the row matches something in a `JTextField`. But an exception is raised and the code below does not tell my why. What can I do?

```
      try{Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

PreparedStatement pstmnt;
try (
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","hr","123")) {

    pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement("delete from TEMP where matricRoll=?");

    pstmnt.setString(1, matricRoll.getText());
    pstmnt.executeUpdate();

            conn.close();
            pstmnt.close();
  GI.setVisible(true);
ED.setVisible(false);
addingToFrame();
settingBounds();  
} catch (SQLException ex) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error");}

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
}
```

Comment: Please post the error stacktrace

Comment: Your outer catch is showing a message dialog but the message from the SQLException is not being given. You need to give the message dialog the text of the exception, ex, with `ex.getMessage()`.

Comment: For future reference, you should format your code in a different way. Many people like the default way Eclipse does it.

Comment: @jeff6times7 the inner catch is displaying the error message.

Comment: @jeff6times7 it shows errorjava.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:ORA-00904

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THANKS TO ALL OF YOUr ATTENTION.. i have found the error .. i was deleting from an invalid column...
here is the solution...

```
       try{
           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
           Connection conn;
           PreparedStatement pstmnt;
       try (conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","hr","123"))
 {

        pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement("delete from TEMP where MATRICRN=?");
        String roll=matricRoll.getText();
        int rollm=Integer.valueOf(roll);

        pstmnt.setInt(1, rollm);
        pstmnt.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Deleted");
            conn.close();
            pstmnt.close();
            GI.setVisible(true);
            ED.setVisible(false);
            addingToFrame();
            settingBounds();  
                } 
    catch (SQLException ex) 
            {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error"+ex);}

       } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException exe) {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,exe);    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### try this:

```
String deleteSQL = "DELETE DBUSER WHERE USER_ID = ?";

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(deleteSQL);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1001);

        // execute delete SQL stetement
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Record is deleted!");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }

    }
```